# RegEx in javascript freezes the screen

Tags: javascript, regex

regEx in javascript freezes the screen. i have code for validating file name and when some extra characters are added like '{' or '[' the screen freezes

```
var acceptFileTypes = /^([a-z\s*\_*\-*\(*\)*\,*\'*\;*\&*\$*\#*\@*\.*\!*0-9]+)+\.(xlsx|ppt|pptx|doc|docx|pdf|tiff|tif|msg)$/i;  

var fileName="business business business business business business return preparation business [.docx"

acceptFileTypes.test(fileName)
```

Comment: Classic catastrophic backtracking, you have `(a+)+` inside the pattern.

Comment: Avoid writing regular expressions if you don't have any clue in what they are.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for highlighting whats wrong. will have to read about it

Comment: @revo :). i'm stuck with supporting  legacy application.  will correct this one. [not my code]